# HTML Forms in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

i am writing html form code with in php script

here it is

```
<?php
  $problem_code="STR";
  echo '<form name="submit-button" action="/codejudge/submit.php?id='.$problem_code.'">';
  echo '<button type="submit" >Submit</button>';
  echo "</form>";
?>
```

But after submitting url look like this `localhost/codejudge/submit.php` ? 
but it should be like this `localhost/codejudge/submit.php?id=STR`

Comment: What if you set `GET` as action of form? `<form method="get" name="submit-button" ` etc.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt — He has, that's the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a form is `method="GET"` (which is the **default**), as this one is, then submitting it will *erase the existing query string* in the action.

Store the data in a hidden input instead.

```
<?php
  $problem_code="STR";
?>
<form name="submit-button" action="/codejudge/submit.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($problem_code); ?>">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should put query variables inside hidden inputs, that's why they exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a method of form submit.

```
$problem_code="STR";
echo '<form method=post name="submit-button" action="/codejudge/submit.php?id='.$problem_code.'">';
echo '<button type="submit" >Submit</button>';
echo "</form>";
```